# Macro gives answer in message box, how to post back to sheet instead

Tags: excel, vba

The Macro matches two columns then showes a message box with the entries that are `not` matched, I have been trying but can not figure out how to post back to sheets("YYY")

Thanks

```
Sub so_whats_missing_2()
Dim u() As Boolean, v()
Dim a, b, c, q

With Sheets("XXX")
    a = .Cells(2, 1).Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row)
  aLR = (.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
With Sheets("YYY")
b = .Cells(2, 1).Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row)
End With

ReDim u(Application.Max(a, b))
ReDim v(UBound(u))

For Each c In b
    u(c) = True
Next

For Each c In a
    If Not u(c) Then v(c) = True
Next

q = "Missing from Sheet2 ..." & vbLf
For c = 1 To UBound(v)
    If v(c) Then q = q & c & vbLf
Next

MsgBox q

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `MsgBox` call and `q`, and put the contents of `c` in the cell you want using the proper `.Cells()` reference on each pass of the loop. `If v(c) then .Cells()... = c`

Comment: thank you Ken, appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `MsgBox q` do something like `Sheets("YYY").Cells(1,2).Value = q`.

Comment: I thought I had try that! must not have gotten it quit right, thanks, Cory